# how to apply multiprocessing to this function?

Tags: python, arrays, multiprocessing

I want to apply multiprocessing a this function, because it takes a long time to run, around 187 seconds, I want to reduce that time. I try to apply multiprocessing but had no success. Somebody could help me?

```
def delete_tree(mat_ady, mat_origin, num_labels, dz_min):
"""Allows you to eliminate low structures or noise in the image.

Parameters
----------
mat_ady : np.ndarray
    Integer matrix where each unique feature (island) in the
    entry has a unique label.
mat_origin : np.ndarray
    original matrix corresponding to the elevation of the trees.
num_labels: int
    Total number of labels in the mat_ady array.
dz_min : float
    Maximum elevation threshold. 
Returns
-------
np.ndarray
    Array without structure low or noise.
"""

tiempo_inicial = time() 

# Each island is traversed and the islands whose maximum value (in the original matrix) exceeds the threshold are eliminated
for label in range(num_labels):
    if np.max(mat_origin[mat_ady == label]) < dz_min:
        mat_origin[mat_ady == label] = 0

#Time of ejecution of the funtion
tiempo_final = time() 
tiempo_ejecucion = tiempo_final - tiempo_inicial
print('El tiempo de ejecucion funcion delete_tree:',tiempo_ejecucion) #En segundos

return mat_origin
```

Comment: Please rewrite the comments in english, so the potential answerer can understand the problem more easily. Also rewrite the title to specify the real problem (e.g. paralellizing of a numpy tree operation) to allow future searches to find it more easily.

Comment: The corrections are already there, thank you for your contribution